# Oracle SQL Developer Error

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT COUNT(empl_asgnmt.internal_empl_id), 
       empl_asgnmt.home_dept_cd, 
       empl_asgnmt.title_cd, 
       empl_asgnmt.pc_ft_pc 
FROM empl_asgnmt 
WHERE empl_asgnmt.appointment_id = '' 
      AND current_date BETWEEN empl_asgnmt.effective_dt 
                           AND empl_asgnmt.expiration_dt;
```

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Comment: Append `GROUP BY    empl_asgnmt.home_dept_cd, 
       empl_asgnmt.title_cd, 
       empl_asgnmt.pc_ft_pc ` clause to the end of the query

Comment: `group by` clause is missing. Second, keep in mind that Oracle treats empty string `''` as null when you write something like this `empl_asgnmt.appointment_id = '' `